# error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining while pushing big repo

Tags: git

Got a problem with duplicating repo, using this guide:https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository

There is no problem with cloning repo (it's a big repo), but when I try to push it to a new repository, have this error:

```
$ git push --mirror https://github.com/myUser/MyProject.git                  
Enumerating objects: 517332, done.
Counting objects: 100% (517332/517332), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (135229/135229), done.
Writing objects: 100% (517332/517332), 745.70 MiB | 209.55 MiB/s, done.
Total 517332 (delta 372827), reused 517332 (delta 372827)
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

`http.postBuffer` already increased to ‭1048576000‬. My network is okay.

Comment: is it possible to configure git to use SSH to push to the new repo? Not that it would explain why this is happening, but would help narrow down the possible sources of the error.

Comment: I tried use ssh, but then (after confrimed ssh key) the whole process freezes and nothing is happening. When I cancel the process, see this:
```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Try to push in smaller batches: `git push https://github.com/myUser/MyProject.git HEAD~1000:master && git push https://github.com/myUser/MyProject.git HEAD~500:master && git push https://github.com/myUser/MyProject.git master:master`